# Does enabling the alternate RXD function on an AVR GPIO pin disable the pull-up functionality?

Tags: avr, uart, pullup, rxd

The datasheet seems to imply that either the `PORT` register *or* the alternate alternate pin function, but not both....

[image]

Since the pull-ups are controlled by the `PORT` register, does this mean that the pull-up are no longer functional when the RXD alternate function is enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in fact documented in the datasheet in the section called "Alternate Port Functions".

As you haven't given a part, the example below is for the ATMega162, but according to the datasheet:

> "The overriding signals may not be present in all port pins, but the
>   figure serves as a generic description applicable to all port pins in
>   the AVR microcontroller family."

...so this information should apply to any microcontroller in the AVR family.

Referring to the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2513-8-bit-AVR-Microntroller-ATmega162_Datasheet.pdf) we find the Alternate Port Functions section starts on Page 68.

At the start of the section we have a general information which explains how the alternate functions work - specifically how the IO ports are controlled by "override signals" which as can be inferred from the name are signals which override various parts of the functionality of the IO port.

According to Table 28 on page 69, for the pull-up resistor, the override signals are `PUOE` (pull-up override enable) and `PUOV` (pull-up override value). When `PUOE = 1` (override enabled), the pull-up resistor is enabled only if `PUOV = 1`. When `PUOE = 0` (override disabled), the pull-up resistor has normal functionality.

[image: Table 28 from Page 69]

So the task is then to work out what values the `PUOE` and `PUOV` signals take when using the RXD alternate function. The answer is given in the various tables following. For the ATMega162, RXD0 is on Port D, bit 0, as per table 38 on page 78.

[image: Table 38 from Page 78]

Now we know which alternate function we are after, lets look for the table referring to override signals for PD0. This can be found in Table 40 on page 80.

[image: Table 40 from Page 80]

Here we can see that for PD0, the values of `PUOE` and `PUOV` are `RXEN0` and `PORTD0 . PUDn` respectively. Breaking it down, this means that whenever the UART Receiver is enabled (`RXEN0 = 1` - see USART register descriptions), then the pull-up resistor override is enabled. That means the pull-up resistor is now controlled by the `PUOV` value. We can see then from the equation that `PUOV = 1` when `(PORTD0 . PUDn) = 1` - meaning when the logical AND of `PORTD0` and `PUDn` is true. This is the case when `PORTD0 = 1` and when `PUDn = 1`.

**TL;DR;** When the RX alternate function is enabled, we can see from the datasheet that the pull-up resistor is still controlled by the `PORTD0` register bit just like in normal (GPIO) operation.

Comment: This is a correct, authoritative, and helpful answer. I believe that this answer does also apply to all parts in the AVR family as per the datasheet, and I have suggested an edit including this info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The pull-up is still connected to the pin even when the RXD alternate function is enabled. I confirmed this on actual hardware.

This is very handy because it means you can use an open drain to drive the RXD pin form a source with a different voltage level without a level converter.